What do square brackets mean in Python function definitions?
While watching a video about Python features, I came across the following code snippet:
def compose[_First, _Second, _Thirt](
    first: Callable[[_First], _Second],
    second: Callable[[_Second], _Third],
) -> Callable[[_First], _Third]:
    return lambda x: second(first(x))

I’m curious about the syntax with square brackets right after the function name, specifically [_First, _Second, _Third]. What is this syntax called? When and how is it used in Python?

P.S. Summary for future readers:

This is called Type Parameter Syntax
It was introduced in Python 3.12 and is detailed in PEP 695
A partial answer to the question is provided in this article on SO
This specific case is described in the documentation on generic functions


https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/#type-parameter-declarations

@dROOOze Does this apply to Python 3.12 and above?

Yes, PEP 695 is introduced and only applies to Python 3.12+. The top of that link mentions the dates and Python versions.

See also What's New In Python 3.12.
